# Google Apps Scripts .getvalues buggy?

Tags: google-apps-script

When I run my script, I get this error message:

**Syntax error: TypeError: Cannot read property "1" from undefined. line: ?**

This is a snippet of my script:

```
var posConts = new Array();
var posContsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dataSheetValuesID).getSheets()[0].getRange('A:A');
var posContsDataValues = posContsData.getValues();

for (ii = 1; ii <= posContsData.getNumRows(); ii++) {
    iii = ii-1;
    posConts[iii] = posContsDataValues[ii][1];
}
```

I had no problems with using the collection in the values[0][0] format before.

Is this a bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusion the indexes. Both arrays start on 0 (as all arrays in javascript). But you're using `ii` which starts on 1 on `posContsDataValues` and zero based `iii` on `posConts`. You're also accessing index `1` on each row, which is wrong, since you get only one column `A:A` and it's also zero-based.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but from your snippet, here is a "fixed" loop.

```
for( var i = 0; i < posContsDataValues.length; ++i )
    posConts.push(posContsDataValues[i][0]);
```

Comment: Hey, that did the trick!

I'm not familiar with .push method yet.  
Thanks for the help hgabreu!

Comment: `push` just appends the parameter to the array. `posConts[i] = ...` would work the same (in this loop, as is).

Answer (score 0):

The array that you get with getValues is indexed by rows & columns so in your case (datarange = column A) there is only 1 column index and it's referenced by [0] since arrays are 0 indexed.
AND you should not iterate beyond the array length.
Try it like this :

```
for (ii = 1; ii < posContsDataValues.length; ii++) {
    iii = ii-1;
    posConts[iii] = posContsDataValues[ii][0];
}
```

best regards,
Serge

Comment: Thanks for the reply Serge.

But it still gives me an error:

Syntax error: TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. line: ?

Comment: I doubt this error occurs on Serge's exact snippet. You probably forgot to change the loop condition from `ii <= posContsData.getNumRows()` to `ii < posContsDataValues.length`. Anyway, I also doubt that, even without the error, this is what you want (as this loop skips the first value).

Answer (score 0):

try to change `iii=ii-1;` by `iii=parseInt(ii)-1;`

Comment: this type problem is only an issue when using the `for..in` loop style, as in `for( ii in posContsDataValues )`. Which is not the case here.